# IRS Income Tax Updated Weekly?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax

We're selling our house, and have been having issues with our buyers lender being faxed the incorrect tax income amount on their tax returns. It's been over two weeks and every time, the IRS says they've fixed the issue, but then once they're faxed again the information is still incorrect.

We're being told that our buyers are being told by the IRS, that they only update the tax returns once a week, on Friday, so the updated tax forms can't be faxed to the lender again until the Monday after that update takes place.

So my questions are these: Is this correct, or is this runaround by the IRS? Note that this has already taken three week, and it's starting to cost both us and our buyers money in lender/rate locking fees along with the sellers of our new home interest fees. Is there some recourse that can be taken against the IRS for the money they are costing us? If this sounds like runaround, what can be done to quickly resolve the issue?